# WooCommerce: hide product data fields(backend)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I want is to hide some product data fields in the backend. More specifically, the price fields.

I know that remove_post_type_support() gets rid of the basic fields. But the woocommerce product prices are not one of them. So, I would something like remove_post_type_support() for woocommerce product prices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd be able to do that unless you want to remove the whole product data metabox where you can remove using `remove_meta_box` function

I think your best option is to disable all default product type and create your own product type with the fields you want.

here's a reference https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-product-type-custom-settings-woocommerce/

had it booked marked for more than a year but I never really tried it.

Another very simple way to hide pricing field is through CSS if you only need to hide it from the back-end.

example

```
function hide_baby_boy_hide() { ?>
<style>
.wp-admin #woocommerce-product-data .pricing, .wp-admin #price span, .wp-admin.post-type-product .price span {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_baby_boy_hide');
```